# "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now" on detail page (Magento2 EE 2.1.7) Update

Tags: magento2, database, cart, addtocart, quote

[image: Error]

How to resolve ???

---

I has changed in vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php:99

Change 'cache_dir' => null
to     'cache_dir' => 'var/cache'.
And not resolve this.

Plsssss help me !!! Thank Alls :D

Answer (score 0):

Check your var/log/exception.log - It should throw an error if it cannot access the var/cache directory. You may need to the full absolute URL. In my case it was something like:

```
'cache_dir' => 'C:/websites/domainname.com/something/var/cache'
```

Please note this is not a good permanent solution as it modifies core files, and may cause issues later. It's better to override the file if possible.