# M2: after add to cart showing error message

Tags: magento2, addtocart, product-view, frontend-error

After add to cart, product added to cart and showing this "**We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now.**" error message.

I have set website and all other necessary fields for product in admin panel.

in exception.log file, showing this details:

```
report.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: Requested store is not found in /XXX/XXX/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:111
```

I have already done re indexing, commands, cache but still above error message is showing.

I have already review this: [//magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200031/we-cant-add-this-item-to-your-shopping-cart-right-now-on-detail-page-magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200031/we-cant-add-this-item-to-your-shopping-cart-right-now-on-detail-page-magento)

Answer (score 1):

Here is way you can solved your issue by just checking the real error.

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php
```

Go to the message and check the error message :-

```
try{

// Your code here

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); die();
    $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
    $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
    return $this->goBack();
}
```